# How to display an "X' in a checked checkbox instead of a checkmark?

Tags: delphi, checkbox, drawing, controls

The CheckBox component displays a checkmark when checked.

I would like to display an 'X' instead.

Comment: I would suggest you to stick to the default UI, unless you have very good reasons to customize it. Usually users do expect a common behavior from application controls, and non-standard applications end up to be less friendly to use. I understand the web bad practices had made ad-hoc UIs quite common, but that's one of the worst sides of web applications, IMHO. Customized controls were also 1990 fashion, but then went out of favour until HTML allowed to slap any image into a page...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
unit CheckboxEx;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Messages, Graphics, Classes, Controls, UxTheme;

type
  TCrossType = (ctChar, ctGDI);
  TCheckboxEx = class(TCustomControl)
  private type
    THoverState = (hsNormal = 1, hsHover = 2, hsPushed = 3);
  private const
    DEFAULT_PADDING = 3;
    DEFAULT_CHECK_CHAR = '✘';
    CHECK_LINE_PADDING = 4;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCaption: TCaption;
    FChecked: boolean;
    FPadding: integer;
    FCheckWidth, FCheckHeight: integer;
    FCheckRect, FTextRect: TRect;
    theme: HTHEME;
    FHoverState: THoverState;
    FCheckFont: TFont;
    FCheckChar: Char;
    FMouseHover: boolean;
    FCrossType: TCrossType;
    procedure SetCaption(const Caption: TCaption);
    procedure SetChecked(Checked: boolean);
    procedure SetPadding(Padding: integer);
    procedure UpdateMetrics;
    procedure CheckFontChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetCheckChar(const CheckChar: char);
    procedure DetermineState;
    procedure SetCrossType(CrossType: TCrossType);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure Click; override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property ParentColor;
    property ParentFont;
    property Color;
    property Visible;
    property Enabled;
    property TabStop default true;
    property TabOrder;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnExit;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnClick;
    property Font;
    property CheckFont: TFont read FCheckFont write FCheckFont;
    property Caption: TCaption read FCaption write SetCaption;
    property Checked: boolean read FChecked write SetChecked default false;
    property Padding: integer read FPadding write SetPadding default DEFAULT_PADDING;
    property CheckChar: Char read FCheckChar write SetCheckChar default DEFAULT_CHECK_CHAR;
    property CrossType: TCrossType read FCrossType write SetCrossType default ctGDI;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Math;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TCheckboxEx]);
end;

var
  Hit: boolean;

function _EnumFontsProcBool(var LogFont: TLogFont; var TextMetric: TTextMetric;
  FontType: Integer; Data: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  hit := SameStr(LogFont.lfFaceName, Pstring(Data)^);
  result := IfThen(hit, 0, 1);
end;

function FontInstalled(const FontName: TFontName): boolean;
var
  LF: TLogFont;
  fn: string;
begin
  hit := false;
  FillChar(LF, sizeOf(LF), 0);
  LF.lfCharSet := DEFAULT_CHARSET;
  fn := FontName;
  EnumFontFamiliesEx(GetDC(0), LF, @_EnumFontsProcBool, cardinal(@fn), 0);
  result := hit;
end;

function IsKeyDown(const VK: integer): boolean;
begin
  IsKeyDown := GetKeyState(VK) and $8000 <> 0;
end;

{ TCheckboxEx }

procedure TCheckboxEx.CheckFontChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  if Enabled then
  begin
    SetChecked(not FChecked);
    SetFocus;
  end;
end;

constructor TCheckboxEx.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TabStop := true;
  FMouseHover := false;
  FChecked := false;
  FPadding := DEFAULT_PADDING;
  FCheckChar := DEFAULT_CHECK_CHAR;
  FCrossType := ctGDI;
  theme := 0;
  FHoverState := hsNormal;
  FCheckFont := TFont.Create;
  FCheckFont.Assign(Font);
  if FontInstalled('Arial Unicode MS') then
    FCheckFont.Name := 'Arial Unicode MS';
  FCheckFont.OnChange := CheckFontChange;
end;

destructor TCheckboxEx.Destroy;
begin
  FCheckFont.Free;
  if theme <> 0 then
    CloseThemeData(theme);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.DetermineState;
var
  OldState: THoverState;
begin
  inherited;
  OldState := FHoverState;
  FHoverState := hsNormal;
  if FMouseHover then
    FHoverState := hsHover;
  if (csLButtonDown in ControlState) or (IsKeyDown(VK_SPACE) and Focused) then
    FHoverState := hsPushed;
  if (FHoverState <> OldState) and UseThemes then
    Invalidate;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  if Key = VK_SPACE then
    DetermineState;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  if Key = VK_SPACE then
  begin
    Click;
    DetermineState;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  DetermineState;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  FMouseHover := true;
  DetermineState;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  DetermineState;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.Paint;
var
  ext: TSize;
  frect: TRect;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Self.Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  if UseThemes then
  begin
    if theme = 0 then
    begin
      theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
      UpdateMetrics;
    end;
    if Enabled then
      DrawThemeBackground(theme,
        Canvas.Handle,
        BP_CHECKBOX,
        ord(FHoverState),
        FCheckRect,
        nil)
    else
      DrawThemeBackground(theme,
        Canvas.Handle,
        BP_CHECKBOX,
        CBS_UNCHECKEDDISABLED,
        FCheckRect,
        nil);
  end
  else
    if Enabled then
      DrawFrameControl(Canvas.Handle,
        FCheckRect,
        DFC_BUTTON,
        DFCS_BUTTONCHECK)
    else
      DrawFrameControl(Canvas.Handle,
        FCheckRect,
        DFC_BUTTON,
        DFCS_BUTTONCHECK or DFCS_INACTIVE);
  Canvas.TextFlags := TRANSPARENT;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle,
    PChar(FCaption),
    length(FCaption),
    FTextRect,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT);
  if Focused then
  begin
    ext := Canvas.TextExtent(FCaption);
    frect := Rect(FTextRect.Left,
      (ClientHeight - ext.cy) div 2,
      FTextRect.Left + ext.cx,
      (ClientHeight + ext.cy) div 2);
    Canvas.DrawFocusRect(frect);
  end;
  if FChecked then
    case FCrossType of
      ctChar:
        begin
          Canvas.Font.Assign(FCheckFont);
          DrawText(Canvas.Handle,
            CheckChar,
            1,
            FCheckRect,
            DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_CENTER);
        end;
      ctGDI:
        begin
          Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
          Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
          Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;
          Canvas.MoveTo(FCheckRect.Left + CHECK_LINE_PADDING, FCheckRect.Top + CHECK_LINE_PADDING);
          Canvas.LineTo(FCheckRect.Right - CHECK_LINE_PADDING, FCheckRect.Bottom - CHECK_LINE_PADDING);
          Canvas.MoveTo(FCheckRect.Right - CHECK_LINE_PADDING, FCheckRect.Top + CHECK_LINE_PADDING);
          Canvas.LineTo(FCheckRect.Left + CHECK_LINE_PADDING, FCheckRect.Bottom - CHECK_LINE_PADDING);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.SetCaption(const Caption: TCaption);
begin
  if not SameStr(FCaption, Caption) then
  begin
    FCaption := Caption;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.SetCheckChar(const CheckChar: char);
begin
  if FCheckChar <> CheckChar then
  begin
    FCheckChar := CheckChar;
    if FChecked then Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.SetChecked(Checked: boolean);
begin
  if FChecked <> Checked then
  begin
    FChecked := Checked;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.SetCrossType(CrossType: TCrossType);
begin
  if FCrossType <> CrossType then
  begin
    FCrossType := CrossType;
    if FChecked then Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.SetPadding(Padding: integer);
begin
  if FPadding <> Padding then
  begin
    FPadding := Padding;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.UpdateMetrics;
var
  size: TSize;
begin
  FCheckWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
  FCheckHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUCHECK);
  if UseThemes then
  begin
    UxTheme.GetThemePartSize(theme, Canvas.Handle, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, nil, TS_DRAW, size);
    FCheckWidth := size.cx;
    FCheckHeight := size.cy;
  end;
  FCheckRect := Rect(0,
                  (ClientHeight - FCheckHeight) div 2,
                  FCheckWidth,
                  (ClientHeight + FCheckHeight) div 2);
  FTextRect := Rect(FCheckWidth + FPadding,
                 0,
                 ClientWidth,
                 ClientHeight);
end;

procedure TCheckboxEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    CM_MOUSELEAVE:
      begin
        FMouseHover := false;
        DetermineState;
      end;
    WM_SIZE:
      begin
        UpdateMetrics;
        Invalidate;
      end;
    WM_SETFOCUS, WM_KILLFOCUS:
      Invalidate;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Now (with `CrossType` set to `ctChar`) you can use any Unicode character as the checkmark, the default choice being ✘ (U+2718: HEAVY BALLOT X). The images below illustrate that the control works both with and without visual themes:

[image: Sample image with visual themes]
[image: Sample image without visual themes enabled]

The following image illustrates that you can choose any character as your checkmark:

[image: Sample image with custom checkmark character]

This character is ✿ (U+273F: BLACK FLORETTE).

If you set `CrossType` to `ctGDI` instead of `ctChar`, the control will draw a cross manually and not a character:

[image: Sample image with GDI ccross]

I didn't use double-buffering this time, because there is no noticable flickering with themes enabled. Without themes, however, there is flickering. To remedy this, simply use a `FBuffer: TBitmap` and draw on `FBuffer.Canvas` instead of `Self.Canvas` and then `BitBlt` at the end of `Paint`, as I do in my other controls here at SO.

Comment: Possible extensions include adding a property specifying the width and height of the checkboxes (`0` indicating the system default size) and allowing the use of a PNG glyph instead of a textual character. These extensions are easily implemented.

Comment: Why use a character for the cross rather than simple GDI drawing? You could come a cropper with font-scaling. +1

Comment: @David: I added that functionality now, together with a keyboard interface (spacebar).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a custom control and paint it yourself.

If this is a real check box then it's a bad idea to avoid the system's default drawing.  However, if you want to do something like a voting form then I could see why you might opt to do this.

Comment: I used to have code to draw a cross in-line in an owner draw grid, but I replaced it with DrawFrameControl and a version for themes.

Comment: @ChuckO What Andreas means is that we will shortly post complete code for such a checkbox!! It's one of his specialities.

Comment: In this case the checkboxes represent items to be left out of a list. Normal usage calls for 'X'ing out.

Comment: @ChuckO that makes sense. Custom draw sounds the right UI solution.

Comment: There is an excellent guide about UI design on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657751(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Idsandon: I agree it is a better idea to stick to the common UI controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the opposite way, anyway, select all items by default and let the user remove the ones who should be left out from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Having checkbutton a serious limitation in designs, who want to stay in VCL, can use BitBtn as a check, using "Kind" property to paint the Cancel or Ok images when user click on it. Also delete after every condition change, the "Caption" property, because the BitBtn must have a square layout to simulate a check. Use also a tLabel at left or right hand as you wish.

```
if lAutoMode = False then
  begin
   lAutoMode := True;
   BitBtn1.Kind := bkOK;
   BitBtn1.Caption := '';
end
else
begin
  lAutoMode := False;
  BitBtn1.Kind := bkAbort;
  BitBtn1.Caption := '';
end;
```

When create the Form, set the initial state for the BitBtn.